# Error while defining id of view in android xml

Tags: android

I make a checkbox in my xml:

```
           <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/protected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

It is showing error: error: invalid symbol 'protected'. Any ideas?

Comment: You cant used  protected because it's system preserved keyword.

Comment: It's a Java Keyword: check this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/protected

Comment: What about calling it `android:id="@+id/chkProtected"`?

Comment: I do not downvote you, but I think here are many similar question's on so, As one link from them i have added in my answer.@berserk

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar Actually I searched for protected specifically, so I found no similar question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:id="@+id/protected"
```

`protected` is a reserved java keyword. It can not be used as name for a variable

Answer (score 1):

You cant used `protected` because it's system reserved keyword. try with different like

```
android:id="@+id/mProtected"
```

check this [Keywords](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/protected)

Answer (score 1):

`protected` is a reserved java keyword. It can not be used as name for a variable

Define like that:

```
<CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/chkbProtected"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

## wrong

As protected  is a keyword in java,so  it won't be used as a variable. if you use protected  it will give you error,both in R.java file and also in xml file.

## solution

Your can use

```
android:id="@+id/_protected"  // it will not give your any error.
```

Comment: What you want to say, are u sure that your solution is correct.

Comment: give a try and let me know.i am sure at my end.

Comment: ahhhhh,sorry i just forgot to add underscore(_) symbol.

Comment: i think then i deserve +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

you cant do that, as it is a **Reserved** word. just like...

```
break else new var
case finally return void
catch for switch while
continue function this with
default if throw
delete in try
do instanceof typeof
abstract enum int short
boolean export interface static
byte extends long super
char final native synchronized
class float package throws
const goto private transient
debugger implements protected volatile
double import public
null
true
false
```

Each resource having entry in java field name inside R.java class
so you can not use **reserved** word

Answer (score 0):

`protected` is a keyword in java.
When you set an id in an XML, it will be compiled into an integer in the file R.java. This means that you will have an integer in your R.java file named protected, which isn't allowed.